# How to copy a DWord Size Data from a array of Byte and conver to DWord type Value in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to convert the C++ code snippet below to Delphi:

```cpp
DWORD n;
memcpy(&n, lpData, sizeof(n)); <==== the C++ data type : LPBYTE lpData = NULL; 
wprintf(L"REG_DWORD - ValueName: %s, Data: %u\n", pValueName, n);
```

I do not know the Delphi part, I've tried some code as below:

```pascal
lpData: array of byte;
n : DWord;
// then do not know how to use 
procedure CopyMemory(Destination: Pointer; Source: Pointer; Length: NativeUInt);
```

Here is the most difficult part to me:

1. I don't know how to convert `lpData` to a pointer.
2. variable `Destination` type is `PByte`, or not?
3. How to get the length?
4. How to convert the destination value to `n` (`Dword` type value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic array is already pointer, so the next code works:

```
var
  lpData: array of byte;
  n : DWord;
begin
  lpData := [$0A, $0B, $0C, $0D];
  CopyMemory(@n, lpData, SizeOf(n));
  Caption := Format('%x', [n]);
```

Note that `lpData` should be initialized.

Also `array of byte;` is doubtful analog of `C++` data type - it is Delphi-specific managed type. Array body might be used as storage, but overall usage might differ.

Direct analog of `LPBYTE` is Delphi `PByte`, sometimes `PByteArray` is convenient. It is worth to describe - how your `lpData` is filled.

Comment: In C/C++, `LPBYTE` is `BYTE*` aka `unsigned char *`.  In Delphi, the equivilent is `PByte` aka `^Byte`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Remy Lebeau: again!!!
for your good answer !!!!
suddenly, I realize one important thing.
it is a memory operation only! 
buffer, buffer pointer, buffer size......3 basic elements !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to deal with this is to use a cast.

```
var
  lpData: PByte;
  n: DWORD;
... 
n := PDWORD(lpData)^;
```